# How to make a test of favicon in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a task to check presence of the favicon on the page. How to do it?  I use Selenium WebDriver.

I made in the same way, addressed according to the link  "http://my_site.com/favicon.ico", and later I checked for existence of a faviсon on this page (also I pulled out an element), but not on main page and my test passed.

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522683/how-can-i-get-sites-favicon-using-selenium

Answer (score 4):

It depends.  There are three cases to consider:

1. The page does not have a favicon.
2. The page has a favicon by virtue of a `favicon.ico` file located in the website's root but does not specify the favicon in HTML.
3. The page specifies a favicon using a `link` element in HTML.

Selenium cannot distinguish between cases (1) and (2).

Selenium *can* check for case (3) the same way you would check for any other element, e.g. using a XPath selector.  For example, if your `link` looks like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

then you might check for that element with an XPath like this:

```
//xpath[@rel='shortcut icon']
```

Wikipedia's [favicon page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use) has a list of other ways to specify the `link` element.

Comment: I think 2 can be solved not with Selenium, but with a bit of Java-code. You can just download the favicon.ico file from the root (http://servername.com/favicon.ico) and compare it with a known copy. Here is some Java code to get an image from an url: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23522335/1088584 if the image download gives an error its situation 1 presumably.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the favicon with Selenium you would have to use another program to grab it. The only way you would be able to get it is if your website rendered the favicon.ico as a link such as

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"
 href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

However typically websites just store the favicon.ico in the root directory and on page request the browser retrieves it and drops it in the address bar or tab or wherever favicons are used. If this is how your favicon is rendered then there will be no code or anything to search for with Selenium.

Also the above code while it does work has some buggy support for IE7.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use for a list of ways to specify a favicon.